AutoComplete.js I am getting error "The name tarekraafat doesnt exists in the current context"
I installed node.js first then install package :
npm i @tarekraafat/autocomplete.js
And added
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@10.2.7/dist/autoComplete.min.js"></script>
Also
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@10.2.7/dist/css/autoComplete.min.css">
However I still get this error
I followed installation steps still getting built error

Unfortunately you just provide two completely independent installation steps of the autocomplete library. It would be way more useful if you can tell what you did to actually use the library. Did you follow: https://tarekraafat.github.io/autoComplete.js/#/usage ?

Razor supports C# and uses the @ symbol to transition from HTML to C#. Razor evaluates C# expressions and renders them in the HTML output.
When an @ symbol is followed by a Razor reserved keyword, it transitions into Razor-specific markup. Otherwise, it transitions into plain HTML.
To escape an @ symbol in Razor markup, use a second @ symbol:
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@10.2.7/dist/autoComplete.min.js"></script>

